# Using Scanner to find letter

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do here is have a user input a sentence or some type of string, then have the scanner search through the string to determine if there is an "e" or "E" in there. If the scanner finds either one of those it will replace them with "xyz." If they are not present then it should return "All is good!" The code I have thus far is:

```
public class Example {
    String userInput;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please write a sentence.");
    userInput = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println(userInput.replace("e","xyz"));
    System.out.println(userInput.replace("E","xyz"));

    in.close();
}
```

As I think you can tell this really just prints the same line twice, once removing a lower case e and the other removing a capital E. I was looking for a way to combine the two replacements and then have it replace and print if it finds an e or just print "All is good!" if there are no "e"s.

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/245069/1393766)

Comment: take a look at this post http://jelaniharris.com/2009/case-insensitive-replaceall-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't related to `Scanner` at all really. Trivial approach:

```
String replaced = userInput.replace("e","xyz").replace("E","xyz");
String out = replaced.equals(userInput) ? "All is good!" : replaced;
System.out.println(out);
```

Or use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
Pattern eE = Pattern.compile("[eE]");
String replaced = eE.matcher(userInput).replaceAll("xyz");
```

Comment: Ouch! Sorry, way too accustomed to Scala where this works as expected.

Comment: Can you explain that the ? does in Java? Can you put the second line into words? "Created a new string....etc."

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to look into [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and its associate [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).  This can give you precisely what you want.

While `String#replaceAll` gives you what you want, it's not entirely semantic; you can certainly replace all of the "e"s with "xyz" and *then* compare them to see if there was no change, but using `Matcher` gives you a bit more obvious control over the logic.

We first need to **compile** a regex, then build a matcher from the *compiled* regex.  If we find a match, we can then replace the strings; otherwise, we can print out our value.

```
String userInput;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please write a sentence.");
userInput = in.nextLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[eE]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userInput);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("xyz"));
} else {
    System.out.println("All is good!");
}
System.out.println(userInput.replaceAll("[eE]","xyz"));
```

Also, don't close the `System.in` stream.  It's not desirable to close that out in case some other part of your application wants to make use of it, or if you want to make use of it later.

Answer (score -1):

Java strings are immutable, so you can't just call `replace` on `userInput` and expect it to be modified in place. You need to save the result of the function call.

Comment: Your advice is sound, but in this case they're only printing out the substitution.  There's nowhere for the string to be saved.